# Importing external XML file with PHP, summing values

Tags: php, xml

Like the title says, I'm importing an external XML file into a site.  It's actually weather data from observation sites around the world.  I can parse and display the data no problem.  My problem is I'm trying to sum up a specific set of data.

Here's the basic code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=kbwi&hoursBeforeNow=65');

for($i=0;$i<=60;$i++)
{
$precip[$i] = $xml->data->METAR[$i]->precip_in;
echo $precip[$i];
}    
?>
```

This will echo all the values from 'precip_in' from the XML file, and it does work.  But if I try to sum up the data in $precip or in 'precip_in' by using array_sum, I get a blank page.  Using var_dump returns "NULL" a bunch of times.

Now, I could manually sum the values by doing something like:

```
$rainTotal = $precip[0]+$precip[1]+$precip[2];
```

But one thing I want to do with this is a 24 hour rainfall total.  The observations aren't always updated at regular or hourly intervals; meaning that if I were to do something like this:

```
$rainTotal = $precip[0]+$precip[1]+$precip[2]...+$precip[23];
```

It would not necessarily give me the 24 hour rain total.  So, I need a way to sum all the rainfall values contained within 'precip_in' or $precip.

Any ideas on how I should proceed?

EDIT:  Some clarifications based on the comments below:

Echoing and var_dump-ing $precip[$i] work fine.  But if I try the following:

```
<?php
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=kbwi&hoursBeforeNow=65');

for($i=0;$i<=60;$i++)
{
$precip[$i] = $xml->data->METAR[$i]->precip_in;
echo array_sum($precip[$i]);
}    
?>
```

I get a blank page.  Doing a var_dump of array_sum($precip[$i]) results in "NULL" a bunch of times in a row.

I have tried casting the XML string as either a float or a string, but I get the same results.

Comment: You're saying that `echo $precip[$i];` outputs the correct values, but `var_dump($precip);` returns `null`?

Comment: "by using array_sum, I get a blank page"  Can you show the code that produces this as well as the related error message that is likely in your apache/php logs?

Answer (score 0):

the value of $xml->data->METAR[$i]->precip_in is an object ((SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) { [0]=> string(5) "0.005" }). It's not numeric, so it has no numeric value. You can cast this to a float however and get the numeric value your were expecting.

```
for($i=0;$i<=60;$i++)
{
  $precip[$i] = (float)$xml->data->METAR[$i]->precip_in;
  echo $precip[$i];
}
```

These float values can be summed.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Yeah I've trying casting it as a float, as a string, etc.  When I do, I am still able to echo $precip[$i], but I still cannot do an array_sum of $precip[$i].  When I do, I get a blank page as a result.  If I do a var_dump of array_sum($precip[$i]), I get a bunch of 'NULL's in a row.

Comment: @Steppin_Razor $precip[$i] is not an array, it's an element in the array at index $i. What do you get if you do array_sum($precip) after your loop?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an `array_sum` on an XPath array return:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=kbwi&hoursBeforeNow=65');

$result = array_sum(array_map("floatval", $xml->xpath('//METAR/precip_in')));

echo $result;
// 10.065
```

Alternatively you can use XPath's `sum()` which requires using DOMDocument and not SimpleXML, specifically [`DOMXPath::evaluate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('https://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=kbwi&hoursBeforeNow=65');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$sum = (float)$xpath->evaluate('sum(//METAR/precip_in)');

echo $sum;
// 10.065
```